# Strange Segmentation Fault with pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list, structure

I should be doing a program that builds a tree from an existing array, with some property. My issue is not about how doing that (I should be doing some recursive fuctions, and it's ok), since when I tried to launch the building function I had some segmentation fault. So I tried to "isolate" the problem and I saw that I had it when I created the root node of the tree. I really couldn't understand why I had that error (since I've been using lists for a while, so, even if I'm not a guru, I'm not completely new in pointers and linked structures neither). I tried to write a very simple main code for seeing what was happening, and I saw that I couldn't even initialize a single node. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elem {
    int info;
    struct elem *p;
    struct elem *left;
    struct elem *right; 
} tree;

typedef tree* tree_punt;

void fill(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        array[i] = i+1;
    }
}

void show(int *array, int size) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    int *array;
    int size;

    size = 7;
    fill(array, size);
    show(array, size);

    printf("array \"address\": %d\n", array);


    tree_punt test;
    printf("tree \"address\": %d\n", test);
    test = (tree_punt)malloc(sizeof(tree));
    test->info = 5;
    printf("info: %d\n", test->info);

 }
```

I have the segmentation fault when I use the malloc for the test pointer. The strange thing is that if I don't put values inside the array I have no issues .... why? Why should the array bother my poor tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use uninitialized pointer:

```
int *array;
fill(array, size);
```

`array` does not point anywhere, and trying to pass it to `fill` causes undefined behaviour.

To fix this you could change to:

```
int size = 7;
int array[size];
```

Comment: perhaps `const int size = 7`

Comment: Thank you so much! I tought I could use pointers in that way too

Comment: @Mark you always have to think about where a pointer is pointing to

Answer (score 0):

Besides not initializing your `int` array, you also print a variable that has garbage value:

```
tree_punt test;
printf("tree \"address\": %d\n", test);
test = (tree_punt)malloc(sizeof(tree));
```

Here, you are printing `test` **before** it has any meaningful value. Just switch the last two lines, and don't use `%d` but instead `%p` (since it's a pointer and not an integer).